# Why are Fed's Tealbooks released with a 5 years lag?

Tags: macroeconomics, federal-reserve, forecasting

In "On DSGE models", Christiano, Eichenbaum & Trabandt (2018) mentions the "so-called Tealbooks" (p.21). They also say that these Tealbooks are released with a 5-years lag.

I was simply wondering why ? I mean I do understand that forecasts possibly give free informations to markets, but 5 years ?

Reference :  [Christiano, Eichenbaum & Trabandt (2018), "On DSGE Models"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gu1Fi89Kz-NWP95wDCsQb7lnLxVaXjV-/view)